# Como verificar o estado um objeto Gtk::RadioMenuItem?

Tags: c++, c++11, gtk

Estou construindo um menu dinamico utilizando gtkmm. O menu é construido da seguinte forma:

```
Gtk::RadioButtonGroup appRadioGroup;
bool groupInitialized = false;

Gtk::Menu *driverSubMenu = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Menu);
driverSubMenu->set_visible(true);

Inicio Loop...

Gtk::RadioMenuItem *appMenuItem = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::RadioMenuItem);
appMenuItem->set_visible(true);
appMenuItem->set_label("Nome da opção");

if (!groupInitialized) {
    appRadioGroup = appMenuItem->get_group();
    appMenuItem->set_active(true);
    groupInitialized = true;
} else {
    appMenuItem->set_group(appRadioGroup);
}

appMenuItem->signal_toggled().connect([this, &appMenuItem]() {
    this->onApplicationSelected(appMenuItem);
});

driverSubMenu->append(*appMenuItem);

Fim Loop...
```

O método que trata o sinal é:

```
void onApplicationSelected(Gtk::RadioMenuItem *item) {
    if(!item) {
        return;
    }

    if(item->get_active()) {
        std::cout << "Item is active " << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Item is not active " << std::endl;
    }

}
```

O meu problema está nesse signal handler. Quando eu tento invocar qualquer método na variavel item eu recebo erros criticos do GTK+.
Por exemplo: ao invocar o método `get_active()` eu recebo o seguinte erro:

`Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_check_menu_item_get_active: assertion 'GTK_IS_CHECK_MENU_ITEM (check_menu_item)' failed`

O que estou fazendo incorretamente?
Como posso verificar corretamente o status de um RadioMenuItem?

Answer (score 0):

A solução para o problema foi utilizar um wrapper da própria biblioteca do sigc++. O método `sigc::bind` serve para passar argumentos extras e serve exatamente para o propósito que eu estava precisando.

Para solucionar alterei o código para ficar da seguinte forma:

```
appMenuItem->signal_toggled().connect(sigc::bind<Glib::ustring>(
                    sigc::mem_fun(this, &DRI::GUI::onApplicationSelected),
                    "Item selecionado"
            ));
```

Adicionei uma propriedade na classe para saber qual o item atual e modifiquei o handler para ficar desta forma:

```
void onApplicationSelected(Glib::ustring item) {
    if(this->estadoAtual != item) {
        this->estadoAtual = item;
        // FAZ ALGUM OUTRO CÓDIGO QUE EU QUERO
    }
}
```